# jQuery merge click event into a single DRY code block

Tags: javascript, jquery

These 2 code blocks essentially are the same just with different elements how would I go about merging them in to single reusable script

```
$('.menu-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-open');
    $('#cart').removeClass('cart-open');

    $(document).one('click', function closeMenu (e){
        //console.log("DF");
        if($('#sidebar').has(e.target).length === 0){
            console.log("DF");
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-open');
        } else {
            $(document).one('click', closeMenu);
        }
    });
});

$('.cart-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-open');
    $('#cart').toggleClass('cart-open');


    $(document).one('click', function closeMenu (e){
        //console.log("DF");
        if($('#cart').has(e.target).length === 0){
            $('#cart').removeClass('cart-open');
        } else {
            $(document).one('click', closeMenu);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining single handler `processMenu` for `click` event ; set selector `elem` within handler utilizing `event.target.className`

```
    var processMenu = function processMenu(e) {
      var elem = $(e.target.className === "menu-button" ? "#sidebar" : "#cart");
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("sidebar-open");
      $("#cart").removeClass("cart-open");

      $(document).one("click", function closeMenu (evt){
        //console.log("DF");
        if(elem.has(evt.target).length === 0){
            console.log("DF");
            elem.removeClass("sidebar-open");
        } else {
            $(document).one("click", closeMenu);
        }
      });
    };

    $(".menu-button, .cart-button").on("click", processMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a comma:

```
$('.menu-button, .cart-button').on('click', function(e) {
    var param = $(this).is('.menu-button') ? "sidebar" : "cart";
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.cart-open').removeClass('cart-open');
    $('.sidebar-open').removeClass('sidebar-open');
    $('#' + param).toggleClass(param + '-open');

    $(document).one('click', function closeMenu (e){
        //console.log("DF");
        if($("#" + param).has(e.target).length === 0){
            console.log("DF");
            $("#" + param).removeClass(param + '-open');
        } else {
            $(document).one('click', closeMenu);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT: Also, use a shorthand if statement to find out if its the sidebar or cart that was clicked, use that in the rest.**